# Homeomorphism between $C(X,\mathbb R^2)$ and $C(X, \mathbb R)^2$

Tags: general-topology

It's been a while since I touched topology. Is there a way for me to define a homeomorphism:

$$h : C(X,\mathbb R^2) \to C(X, \mathbb R)^2 $$

I thought of maybe looking at it differently (since the inverse is also a homeomorphism), i.e. looking for: $$\hat h : C(X, \mathbb R)^2 \to C(X,\mathbb R^2)  $$

and then doing maybe something like:

$$ (f,g) \mapsto (f+g, f+g)$$

or

$$ (f,g) \mapsto (fg, fg)$$

but I don't see why these would be a bijection.

Comment: What is $X$ here? A topological space? In any case, how the topologies on $C(X,\mathbb R)$ and $C(X,\mathbb R^2)$ are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not only an homeomorphism, but a linear isomorphism between that two vector spaces (the topology is that one compatible with the vector space structure). The linear map $h$ sends $F$ to the couple $(\pi_1\circ F, \pi_2\circ F)$ , where $\pi_i\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

The converse one sends $(f,g)$ to $F\colon X\to \mathbb{R}^2$, $F(x):=(f(x),g(x))$.